# Rails 5 - has_many :through with nested_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a simple application to record our bid results on construction projects.  I have all of my other models and views working, and I'm left with my last portion.  This last portion requires that I record our competitors' bid amounts by each trade.  I'm trying to use has_many :through and nested_form to accomplish this.  Here are my models, and the schema.  I can't seem to figure out how to use nested form to both select the company, the trade they are performing, and their bid.

bid.rb

```
class Bid < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :competitors
  has_many :companies, through: :competitors
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies, allow_destroy: true
end
```

company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :competitors
   has_many :bids, through: :competitors
end
```

bid.rb (my join table)

```
class Competitor < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :bid
   belongs_to :company
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "bids", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "number"
    t.date "date"
    t.boolean "bond_required"
    t.boolean "performance_bond_required"
    t.string "result"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "county"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "region"
    t.string "union_or_open_shop"
    t.string "owner_pm"
    t.string "bid_day_volume"
    t.string "bid_day_margin"
    t.string "completed_volume"
    t.string "completed_margin"
    t.integer "market_id"
    t.integer "owner_id"
    t.integer "architect_id"
    t.integer "estimator_id"
    t.integer "foreman_id"
    t.integer "project_manager_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "public_opening"
  end

  create_table "companies", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "competitors", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer "bid_id"
    t.integer "company_id"
    t.string "trade"
    t.string "bid_amount"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["bid_id", "company_id"], name: "index_competitors_on_bid_id_and_company_id"
  end
```

Here is a simplified version of my view (I can't figure out how to add the trade select or the bid_amount without breaking the view).

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :name %>
  <%= form.text_field :name, id: :bid_name %>
</div>

<%= nested_form_for @bid do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :companies do |company_form| %>
    <%= company_form.text_field :name %>
    <%= company_form.link_to_remove "Remove this company" %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a company", :companies %></p>
<% end %>

<div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Currently, I can't even get my view to post if I click on Submit when the nested_form is in the view (if I remove that block it posts fine).  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

According [to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083687/accessing-nested-model-attributes-inside-a-fields-for-without-using-formbuilder#4084357), you can access a FormBuilder's object by `f.object`. So, you should be able to `company_form.object.trade` and `company_form.object.bid_amount` to access the objects attributes.

As for the form failing to submit, try following the [nested_form_for gem's documentation on Strong Parameters](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#strong-parameters)

> For Rails 4 or people using the "strong_parameters" gem, here is an example:
>
> params.require(:project).permit(:name, tasks_attributes: [:id, :name,
>   :_destroy])
>
> The :id is to make sure you do not end up with a whole lot of tasks.
>
> The :_destroy must be there so that we can delete tasks.